# Centered lightbox with dynamic height

Tags: html, css, lightbox, centering

I'm working on a lightbox. I need it to be dynamically sized based on its content. But I also need it to be centered in the screen. I'm trying something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="lightbox-background">
    <div class="lightbox">
        LIGHTBOX CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lightbox-background {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
}

.lightbox {
    background-color: white;
    width: 780px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: 90%;
}
```

I couldn't make it work. I'd like to avoid using JS, if possible. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with `vertical-align: middle` as well as the `:before` selector on the parent container. Check out my fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/GA5K3/2/**

Comment: It took some time till I understand why it works. Thanks for the help.
You can also set "font-size: 0;" to the container and "font-size: 14px" to its child in order to remove the white space between the inline-block elements. If your container is too small, an extra white space may cause an uncentered result.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I know to center vertically with CSS is to absolute position top 50% then set a top margin negitave half height of element.

Since you don't know the height you'll have to use JS.

Maybe someone has a better technique.